# JavaScript replace all / with \ in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a javascript file that is ran through a windows job using cscript.  However, I can't seem to fix this thing to work correctly.  Inside the file, it basically takes a URL and transforms it to a UNC path.

ex: http://mysite.com/document1.htm to \myserver\document1.htm

However, I can't seem to get the /'s to goto \'s and am at a loss why.

I've tried 2 things basically

```
1) str = str.replace(/\/g, "\\");
2) str = str.replace("/", "\\");
```

Any idea why it wont work?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: +1 Really interesting, after it replaces the first slash, it makes it scape the second.. really interesting..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\//g, "\\");
```

the `/` on the end is the normal `/pattern/` format, you need an extra for your `\` escape, [you can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/LKKJS/).

Comment: And `str = str.replace("/", "\\");` does not work because, unless otherwise noted (by a regex with the `g` modifier), JavaScript only replaces the first occurrence.

Comment: is that just the regex for \ or is there another escape char in there that I can't see.  It works fine but would like to understand why

Comment: that is the world's greatest link! I've been looking for something like this forever.

Comment: @Dave - The ` \ ` is just to escape the ` / `, is that what you mean? I'm unclear on your comment.

Comment: Pretty much.  I was thinking the // was / escaped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following trick:

```
str = str.split("/").join("\\");
```

More generally:

```
function replaceAll(str, a, b) {
    return str.split(a).join(b);
}
```

This avoids regular expression nightmares.