# How can I replace '/' in a Javascript string with another character

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript replace all / with \ in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858552/javascript-replace-all-with-in-a-string)

I have a `date='13/12/2010'` I want to replace this '/' to '_' or something else.

I read [this](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)  But I do not know how can that applied for my case .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a global RegEx (g = global = replace all occurrences) for [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
date = date.replace(/\//g, '_');
```

`\/` is the escaped form of `/`. This is required, because otherwise the `//` will be interpreted as a comment. Have a look at the syntax highlighting:

```
date = date.replace(///g, '_');
```

Answer (score 3):

One easiest thing :)

```
var date='13/12/2010';
alert(date.split("/").join("_")); // alerts 13_12_2010
```

This method doesn't invoke regular expression engine and most efficient one

Comment: `split` / `join` is not usually more efficient than a single call to `replace`.  Regular expressions are less expensive than you think.

Answer (score 1):

You can try escaping the `/` character like this -

```
date.replace( /\//g,"_");
```